# Get method by pathVariable in postMan passed but in mockMvc faile and return 404 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-test, mockmvc

I have a get type method in the controller in Spring Boot, which is passed in Postman and returns data, but in MockMvc it failed and gives a 404 error.

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
```

...

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

in MyController:

```
   @GetMapping("user/get/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return userService.getUserById(id)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
```

in Test:

```
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    void getUserById() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/user/get/{id}",1L).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

in Postman:
[image: no problem]

I am having trouble running the test

Comment: can you add "andDo(print())"  in mockmvc like this `mockMvc.perform(get("/user/get/{id}",1L)).andDo(print())` and update the full error message?

Comment: Do you have @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) or @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) on class level?

Comment: @Feelfree no,i dont have but version spring boot is 2.7.6

Comment: Try to add 1 of this annotation on class level